# Create an event or function or css style that will show the corresponding table column

Tags: html, css

I am using ASP.NET and I am pretty new to it. I want to know about events and functions that will highlight the corresponding event according to the day button I pressed:

```
<td class="style2">
<asp:Button ID="Monday" runat="server" BackColor="#009933" Height="52px" Text="Monday" Width="1259px" />

Protected Sub Monday_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Monday.Click
        Response.Redirect("index2.html")
    End Sub

   <td class="style2" bgcolor="#cc00ff" >

 CS-402<br />
Sir Hashim
      <br/>
 Web Engineering
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want to achieve.

First of all, I would recommend you to separate 'business logic' of your application and UI logic (logic of your presentation layer). In your case `Monday_Click` is a part of the business logic. It should be placed away from the `.aspx` part (to the `.aspx.cs`).

Logic that is responsible for the UI behavior (e.g. highlight something on a page) can be written in JavaScript. You can use jQuery library to simplify it.

Regarding your question. You can add a `OnClientClick="highlighSomething()"` event to the button and add this script at the bottom of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    function highlighSomething(){
        var element = $('td.style2'); // find a cell. Use jQuery for this
        element.css("background-color", "yellow"); // change bg color
    }
</script>
```

P.S. If you are new to the ASP.NET I recommend you to forget about WebForms and to start learning MVC. It's much easier and much better. Almost all new ASP.NET websites are written on mvc, not on WebForms.

Comment: well yes i m new to asp.net and i am also thinking to try MVC thanks for your help